# android permission

Tags: android

permission failure :android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO from uid =10053 pid =1499

why is this error happening eventhough i added

'uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" ',android.permission.CAMERA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax appears to be wrong. For example, there are no commas anywhere in the `<uses-permission>` element. Put each permission in a separate `<uses-permission>` element.

Comment: while writing i just done like that
in app both are different like u mentioned

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```